# change pointer passed by value

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-value

I have given a function `foo(struct node *n)` where `n` is the head node in a linked list.
Now `foo` should change `n` s.t. it points to the end of the list.

But is this possible with this function signature?

Assuming `t` is the pointer to the end of the list:

- `n = t` won't work because the pointer is passed by value.
- `*n = *t` won't work because I would overwrite the head of the list.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 6):

You would need to use a pointer to a pointer:

```
foo(struct node **n)
```

To change what `n` points to, you do:

```
*n = t;
```

Answer (score 5):

No, because you have a copy of the value of the pointer that's been passed in.  You have no access to the original pointer that was passed in.  In order to modify the pointer outside the function the sig would need to be foo( struct node **n).

Comment: `a copy of the value of the pointer` - I do understand that but not completely. We pass in a pointer, why can't we change it? It's a pointer after all.

Comment: Maybe this other post will clarify the matter for you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604946/pointer-to-pointer-clarification/21605097#21605097

Answer (score 4):

You didn't miss anything. It's not possible with the given function declaration.

As you wrote, the pointer is passed by value, therefore if changed, it won't propagate to the original variable.

You need to change the prototype to `foo(struct node **n);` or `struct node *foo(struct node *n);` and return the new pointer as result.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot change any argument passed by value.

Comment: The function receives a copy of the pointer; therefore, the pointer itself was passed by value. Of course, what the pointer points to is, in effect, being passed by reference.

Comment: Note that you *can* pass a pointer by reference. But this is done by passing the address of the pointer. In that case, you are actually passing a pointer to a pointer. But you are still passing *some* pointer, and the pointer you pass will always be passed by value.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change `n` and have the caller see the change. You *can* change `n->prev->next` and `n->next->prev` though - that may be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible for the change to be reflected in the calling function. However, inside `foo`, you can change `n` to your heart's content.

```
int foo(struct node *n) {
    n = NULL; /* ok */
}
```