# Pointer to pointer clarification

Tags: c, pointers

I was following this [tutorial](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx8.html) about how does a *pointer to a pointer* work.

Let me quote the relevant passage:

---

> ```
>     int i = 5, j = 6, k = 7;
>     int *ip1 = &i, *ip2 = &j;
> ```
>
> Now we can set
>
> ```
>     int **ipp = &ip1;
> ```
>
> and `ipp` points to `ip1` which points to `i`. `*ipp` is `ip1`, and `**ipp` is `i`, or 5. We can illustrate the situation, with our familiar box-and-arrow notation, like this:
>
> [image]
>
> If then we say
>
> ```
>     *ipp = ip2;
> ```
>
> we've changed the pointer pointed to by `ipp` (that is, `ip1`) to contain a copy of `ip2`, so that it (`ip1`) now points at `j`:
>
> [image]

---

My question is: Why in the second picture, is `ipp` still pointing to `ip1` but not `ip2`?

Comment: please, add the type of `ipp` when defining it, so your question is complete ;-)

Comment: The way you've lined up your pictures, the first row are all objects of type `int`, the second row are all `int *` and ipp is `int **`. When you say `*ipp = ip2;` you are reading and writing only on the `int *` row of your diagram.

Comment: Do you know how symlinks work? Pointers are sort of like symlinks (only you have to declare at compile time exactly how many layers of pointers you can have).

Comment: Did you draw those diagrams by hand? If not, what tool did you use?

Comment: Because `ipp` pointing to `ip1` so `*ipp = ip2` is same as `ip1 = ip2`

Comment: Can we please stop writing asteriks that far away from the pointed type? `int **ipp` is far less intuitive than `int** ipp`, especially when `**ipp` means a completely different thing outside of type declarations.

Comment: @Darkhogg `int **ipp` seems quite intuitive for me. It means, I'm making `**ipp` an `int`. Which is true.

Comment: @user54609 I have never seen it that way. Thinking `ipp` is a pointer to a pointer of `int` (aka `int**`) seems easier for me.

Comment: @user54609 meanings and personal intuitiveness apart, consider this: The type of `ipp` is `int**`, so **just write `int**` instead of magical *"`imp` dereference is an int"* understandings**.

Comment: @Manu343726 But on `int** a, b`, you don't get two pointers. So here it is better written as `int **a, b, *c, ***d`. (No, don't write this, it is badly readable. But if you'd ever would due to whatever reason, it would count this way.)

Comment: because you did not change the value of `ipp`

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Forget for a second about the pointing analogy.  What a pointer really contains is a memory address.  The `&` is the "address of" operator - i.e. it returns the address in memory of an object.  The `*` operator gives you the object a pointer refers to, i.e. given a pointer containing an address, it returns the object at that memory address.  So when you do `*ipp = ip2`, what you are doing is `*ipp` get the object at the address held in `ipp` which is   `ip1` and then assign to `ip1` the value stored in `ip2`, which is the address of `j`.

**Simply**
`&` --> Address of
`*` --> Value at

Comment: & and * were never so easy

Comment: I believe the main source of confusion is due to the ambiguity of the * operator, which during variable declaration is used to indicate that the variable, in fact, is a pointer to a certain data type. But, on the other hand, it is also used in statements to access the contents of the variable pointed at by a pointer (dereferencing operator).

Answer (score 43):

Because you changed the value pointed to by `ipp` not the value of `ipp`. So, `ipp` still points to `ip1` (the value of `ipp`), `ip1`'s value is now the same as `ip2`'s value, so they both point to `j`.

This:

```
*ipp = ip2;
```

is the same as:

```
ip1 = ip2;
```

Comment: May be worth pointing out the difference between `int *ip1 = &i` and `*ipp = ip2;`, i.e. if you remove the `int` from the first statement then the assignments look very similar, but the `*` is doing something very different in the two cases.

Answer (score 22):

Like most beginner questions in the C tag, this question can be answered by going back to first principles:

- A pointer is a kind of value.
- A variable contains a value.
- The `&` operator turns a variable into a pointer.
- The `*` operator turns a pointer into a variable.

(Technically I should say "lvalue" instead of "variable", but I feel it is more clear to describe mutable storage locations as "variables".)

So we have variables:

```
int i = 5, j = 6;
int *ip1 = &i, *ip2 = &j;
```

Variable `ip1` *contains* a pointer. The `&` operator turns `i` into a pointer and that pointer value is assigned to `ip1`. So `ip1` *contains* a pointer to `i`.

Variable `ip2` *contains* a pointer. The `&` operator turns `j` into a pointer and that pointer is assigned to `ip2`. So `ip2` *contains* a pointer to `j`.

```
int **ipp = &ip1;
```

Variable `ipp` contains a pointer. The `&` operator turns variable `ip1` into a pointer and that pointer value is assigned to `ipp`. So `ipp` contains a pointer to `ip1`.

Let's sum up the story so far:

- `i` contains 5
- `j` contains 6
- `ip1` contains "pointer to `i`"
- `ip2` contains "pointer to `j`"
- `ipp` contains "pointer to `ip1`"

Now we say

```
*ipp = ip2;
```

The `*` operator turns a pointer back into a variable. We fetch the value of `ipp`, which is "pointer to `ip1` and turn it into a variable. What variable? `ip1` of course!

Therefore this is simply another way of saying

```
ip1 = ip2;
```

So we fetch the value of `ip2`. What is it? "pointer to `j`". We assign that pointer value to `ip1`, so `ip1` is now "pointer to `j`"

We only changed one thing: the value of `ip1`:

- `i` contains 5
- `j` contains 6
- `ip1` contains "pointer to `j`"
- `ip2` contains "pointer to `j`"
- `ipp` contains "pointer to `ip1`"

> Why does `ipp` still point to `ip1` and not `ip2`?

A variable changes when you assign to it. Count the assignments; there cannot be more changes to variables than there are assignments!  You start by assigning to `i`, `j`, `ip1`, `ip2` and `ipp`.  You then assign to `*ipp`, which as we've seen means the same as "assign to `ip1`". Since you didn't assign to `ipp` a second time, it didn't change!

If you wanted to change `ipp` then you'll have to actually assign to `ipp`:

```
ipp = &ip2;
```

for instance.

Answer (score 21):

hope  this piece of code can help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 5, j = 6, k = 7;
    int *ip1 = &i, *ip2 = &j;
    int** ipp = &ip1;
    printf("address of value i: %p\n", &i);
    printf("address of value j: %p\n", &j);
    printf("value ip1: %p\n", ip1);
    printf("value ip2: %p\n", ip2);
    printf("value ipp: %p\n", ipp);
    printf("address value of ipp: %p\n", *ipp);
    printf("value of address value of ipp: %d\n", **ipp);
    *ipp = ip2;
    printf("value ipp: %p\n", ipp);
    printf("address value of ipp: %p\n", *ipp);
    printf("value of address value of ipp: %d\n", **ipp);
}
```

it outputs:

[image]

Answer (score 13):

My very personal opinion is that pictures with arrows pointing this way or that make pointers harder to understand. It does make them seem like some abstract, mysterious entities. They are not.

Like everything else in your computer, pointers are *numbers*. The name "pointer" is just a fancy way of saying "a variable containing an address".

Therefore, let me stir things around by explaining how a computer actually works.

We have an `int`, it has the name `i` and the value 5. This is stored in memory. Like everything stored in memory, it needs an address, or we wouldn't be able to find it. Lets say `i` ends up at address 0x12345678 and its buddy `j` with value 6 ends up just after it. Assuming a 32-bit CPU where int is 4 bytes and pointers are 4 bytes, then the variables are stored in physical memory like this:

```
Address     Data           Meaning
0x12345678  00 00 00 05    // The variable i
0x1234567C  00 00 00 06    // The variable j
```

Now we want to point at these variables. We create one pointer to int, `int* ip1`, and one `int* ip2`. Like everything in the computer, these pointer variables get allocated somewhere in memory too. Lets assume they end up at the next adjacent addresses in memory, immediately after `j`. We set the pointers to contain the addresses of the variables previously allocated: `ip1=&i;` ("copy the address of i into ip1") and `ip2=&j`. What happens between the lines is:

```
Address     Data           Meaning
0x12345680  12 34 56 78    // The variable ip1(equal to address of i)
0x12345684  12 34 56 7C    // The variable ip2(equal to address of j)
```

So what we got were just yet some 4 byte chunks of memory containing numbers. There's no mystical or magical arrows anywhere in sight.

In fact, just by looking at a memory dump, we can't tell whether the address 0x12345680 contains an `int` or `int*`. The difference is how our program chooses to use the contents stored at this address. (The task of our program is actually just to tell the CPU what to do with these numbers.)

Then we add yet another level of indirection with `int** ipp = &ip1;`. Again, we just get a chunk of memory:

```
Address     Data           Meaning
0x12345688  12 34 56 80    // The variable ipp
```

The pattern does seem familiar. Yet another chunk of 4 bytes containing a number.

Now, if we had a memory dump of the above fictional little RAM, we could manually check where these pointers point. We peek at what's stored at the address of the `ipp` variable and find the contents 0x12345680. Which is of course the address where `ip1` is stored. We can go to that address, check the contents there, and find the address of `i`, and then finally we can go to that address and find the number 5.

So if we take the contents of ipp, `*ipp`, we will get the address of the pointer variable `ip1`. By writing `*ipp=ip2` we copy ip2 into ip1, it is equivalent to `ip1=ip2`. In either case we would get

```
Address     Data           Meaning
0x12345680  12 34 56 7C    // The variable ip1
0x12345684  12 34 56 7C    // The variable ip2
```

---

(These examples were given for a big endian CPU)

Comment: Though I take your point, there is value in thinking of pointers as abstract, mysterious entities. Any particular *implementation* of pointers is just numbers, but the implementation strategy you sketch is not a *requirement* of an implementation, it's just a common strategy. Pointers need not be the same size as an int, pointers need not be addresses in a flat virtual memory model, and so on; these are merely implementation details.

Comment: @EricLippert I think one can make this example more abstract by not using actual memory addresses or data blocks. If it was a table stating something like `location, value, variable` where location was `1,2,3,4,5` and value was `A,1,B,C,3`, the corresponding idea of pointers could be explained easily without the use of arrows, which are inherently confusing. With whatever implementation one chooses, a value exists at some location, and this is piece of the puzzle that becomes obfuscated when modeling with arrows.

Comment: @EricLippert In my experience, most of the would-be C programmers who have problems understanding pointers, are those who were fed abstract, artificial models. Abstraction is _not_ helpful, because the whole purpose of the C language today, is that it's close to the hardware. If you are learning C but don't intend to write code close to the hardware, _you are wasting your time_. Java etc is a much better choice if you don't want to know how computers work, but just do high level programming.

Comment: @EricLippert And yes, various obscure implementations of pointers may exist, where the pointers don't necessarily correspond to addresses. But drawing arrows aren't going to help you understand how those work either. At some point you have to leave the abstract thinking and get down to the hardware level, otherwise you should not be using C. There are many far more suitable, modern languages intended for purely abstract high-level programming.

Comment: @Lundin: I'm not a big fan of arrow diagrams either; the notion of an arrow *as data* is a tricky one. I prefer to think of it abstractly but without arrows. The `&` operator on a variable gives you a coin that represents that variable. The `*` operator on that coin gives you back the variable. No arrows required!

Comment: Sidenote- MISRA C:2004 Rule 17.5 "The declaration of objects should contain no more than 2 levels of pointer indirection." Use of more than 2 levels of indirection can seriously impair the ability to understand the behaviour of the code, and should therefore be avoided. @Lundin- Ur answers are brilliant :)

Comment: @Vector9 Nobody has used more than 2 levels here, so I don't see how that is relevant? Also MISRA-C:2004 is outdated, time to upgrade to MISRA-C:2012.

Comment: Was just pointing out to anyone who reads this not to use more than 2 levels. No arguments related to the concepts you have explained. Will get hold of 2012 :)

Answer (score 8):

Notice the assignments:

```
ipp = &ip1;
```

results `ipp` to point to `ip1`.

so for `ipp` to point to `ip2`, we should change in the similar manner,

```
ipp = &ip2;
```

which we are clearly not doing. Instead we are changing the **value at address** pointed by `ipp`.
By doing the folowing

```
*ipp = ip2;
```

we are just replacing the value stored in `ip1`.

`ipp = &ip1` , means `*ipp = ip1 = &i`, 
Now, `*ipp = ip2 = &j`.
So, `*ipp = ip2` is essentially same as `ip1 = ip2`.

Answer (score 5):

```
ipp = &ip1;
```

No later assignment has changed the value of `ipp`. This is why it still points to `ip1`.

What you do with `*ipp`, i.e., with `ip1`, does not change the fact that `ipp` points to `ip1`.

Answer (score 5):

Because when you say

```
*ipp = ip2
```

you're saying the 'object pointed by `ipp`' to point the direction of memory that `ip2` is pointing.

You're not saying `ipp` to point `ip2`.

Answer (score 5):

> My question is: Why in the second picture, ipp is still point to ip1 but not ip2?

you placed nice pictures, I'm going to try to make nice ascii art:

Like @Robert-S-Barnes said in his answer: *forget about pointers*, and what points to what, but think in terms of memory. Basically, an `int*` means that it contains the address of a variable and an `int**` contains the address of a variable that contains the address of a variable. Then you can use the pointer's algebra to access the values or the addresses: `&foo` means `address of foo`, and `*foo` means `value of the address contained in foo`.

So, as pointers is about dealing with memory, the best way to actually make that "tangible" is to show what the pointers algebra does to the memory.

So, here's your program's memory (simplified for the purpose of the example):

```
name:    i   j ip1 ip2 ipp
addr:    0   1   2   3   4
mem : [   |   |   |   |   ]
```

when you do your initial code:

```
int i = 5, j = 6;
int *ip1 = &i, *ip2 = &j;
```

here's how your memory looks like:

```
name:    i   j ip1 ip2
addr:    0   1   2   3
mem : [  5|  6|  0|  1]
```

there you can see `ip1` and `ip2` gets the addresses of `i` and `j` and `ipp` still does not exists.
Don't forget that addresses are simply integers stored with a special type.

Then you declare and defined `ipp` such as:

```
int **ipp = &ip1;
```

so here's your memory:

```
name:    i   j ip1 ip2 ipp
addr:    0   1   2   3   4
mem : [  5|  6|  0|  1|  2]
```

and then, you're changing the value pointed by the address stored in `ipp`, which is
the address stored in `ip1`:

```
*ipp = ip2;
```

the program's memory is

```
name:    i   j ip1 ip2 ipp
addr:    0   1   2   3   4
mem : [  5|  6|  1|  1|  2]
```

N.B.: as `int*` is a special type, I prefer to always avoid declaring multiple pointers on the same line, as I think the `int *x;` or `int *x, *y;` notation can be misleading. I prefer to write `int* x; int* y;`

HTH

Comment: with your example, initial value of `ip2` should be `3` not `4`.

Comment: oh, I just changed the memory so it matches the order of declaration. I guess I fixed that doing so?

Answer (score 4):

If you add the dereference operator `*` to the pointer, you redirect from the pointer to the pointed-to object.

Examples:

```
int i = 0;
int *p = &i; // <-- N.B. the pointer declaration also uses the `*`
             //     it's not the dereference operator in this context
*p;          // <-- this expression uses the pointed-to object, that is `i`
p;           // <-- this expression uses the pointer object itself, that is `p`
```

Therefore:

```
*ipp = ip2; // <-- you change the pointer `ipp` points to, not `ipp` itself
            //     therefore, `ipp` still points to `ip1` afterwards.
```

Answer (score 3):

If you'd want `ipp` to point to `ip2`, you'd have to say `ipp = &ip2;`. However, this would leave `ip1` still pointing to `i`.

Answer (score 3):

Very beginning you set,

```
ipp = &ip1;
```

Now dereference it as,

```
*ipp = *&ip1 // Here *& becomes 1  
*ipp = ip1   // Hence proved
```

Answer (score 3):

Considere each variable represented like this:

```
type  : (name, adress, value)
```

so your variables should be represented like this

```
int   : ( i ,  &i , 5 ); ( j ,  &j ,  6); ( k ,  &k , 5 )

int*  : (ip1, &ip1, &i); (ip1, &ip1, &j)

int** : (ipp, &ipp, &ip1)
```

As the value of `ipp` is `&ip1` so the inctruction:

```
*ipp = ip2;
```

changes the value at the addess `&ip1` to the value of `ip2`, which means `ip1` is changed:

```
(ip1, &ip1, &i) -> (ip1, &ip1, &j)
```

But `ipp` still:

```
(ipp, &ipp, &ip1)
```

So the value of `ipp` still `&ip1` which means it still points to `ip1`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are changing the pointer of `*ipp`. It means

1. `ipp` (varaiable name)----go inside.
2. inside `ipp` is address of `ip1`.
3. now `*ipp` so go to (adress of inside) `ip1`.

Now we are at `ip1`.
`*ipp`(i.e.`ip1`) = `ip`2.
`ip2` contain address of `j`.so `ip1` content will be replace by contain of ip2(i.e. address of j),
WE ARE NOT CHANGING `ipp` CONTENT.
THAT'S IT.

Answer (score 1):

`*ipp = ip2;` implies:

Assign `ip2` to the variable pointed to by `ipp`. So this is equivalent to:

```
ip1 = ip2;
```

If you want the address of `ip2` to be stored in `ipp`, simply do:

```
ipp = &ip2;
```

Now `ipp` points to `ip2`.

Answer (score 0):

`ipp` can hold a value of (i.e point to) a *pointer to pointer* type object. When you do

```
ipp = &ip2;
```

then the `ipp` contains the **address of the variable (pointer) `ip2`**, which is (`&ip2`) of type *pointer to pointer*. Now the arrow of `ipp` in second pic will point to `ip2`.

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator) says:
The `*` operator is a dereference operator operates on pointer variable, and returns an [**l-value**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)) (variable) equivalent to the value at pointer address. This is called dereferencing the pointer.

Applying `*` operator on `ipp` derefrence it to a l-value of *pointer to `int`* type. The dereferenced l-value `*ipp` is of type *pointer to `int`*, it can hold the address of an `int` type data. After the statement

```
ipp = &ip1;
```

`ipp` is holding the address of `ip1` and `*ipp` is holding the address of (pointing to) `i`. You can say that `*ipp` is an alias of `ip1`. Both `**ipp` and `*ip1` are alias for `i`.
By doing

```
 *ipp = ip2;
```

`*ipp` and `ip2` both points to same location but `ipp` is still pointing to `ip1`.

What `*ipp = ip2;` does actually is that it copies the contents of `ip2` (the address of `j`) to `ip1` (as `*ipp` is an alias for `ip1`), in effect making both pointers `ip1` and `ip2` pointing to the same object (`j`).
So, in the second figure, **arrow of `ip1` and `ip2` is pointing to `j` while `ipp` is still pointing to `ip1` as no modification is done to change the value of `ipp`**.