# linked list: insert end function not working

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};

void insertEnd(struct node *l,int val) {
  struct node *temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  temp->data=val;
  temp->next=NULL;
  if (l==NULL) l=temp;
  struct node* p=l;
  while (p->next!=NULL) p=p->next;
  p->next=temp;
}

void display(struct node *l) {
  struct node *p=l;
  if (p==NULL) printf("Empty list");
  while (p!=NULL) {
    printf("%d ",p->data);
    p=p->next;
  }
}

int main() {
  struct node *l=NULL;
  insertEnd(l,4);
  insertEnd(l,5);
  insertEnd(l,6);
  insertEnd(l,7);
  display(l);
}
```

This is a very basic code for creating a linked list by inserting elements from the end and displaying it. But this keeps displaying empty list and i can't understand why. please help me out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pointer to pointer clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604946/pointer-to-pointer-clarification)

Comment: You give a copy of NULL as parameter to `insertEnd()`. After executing the function, it will still be NULL. See the proposed duplicate about how to solve that with pointer to pointer concept.

Answer (score 0):

In `main()`, `struct node` pointer `l` is initialised with `NULL`. When you pass `l` to `insertEnd()`, you are actually passing `NULL`. If you want to make changes to pointer in another function, pass the address of pointer. You should do

```
void insertEnd(struct node **l,int val) {
  .....
  if (*l==NULL) *l=temp;
  struct node* p=*l;
  .....
}
    
int main() {
  struct node *l=NULL;
  // pass the address of l to insertEnd()
  insertEnd(&l,4);
  insertEnd(&l,5);
  .....
}
```

Even after making above changes, you code will not work fine because there is one more problem in your `insertEnd()`. When inserting the first node to list, it end up creating circular list i.e. the `next` of the first node point to itself. This is happening due to this part of `insertEnd()`:

```
  // Assuming that first parameter of insertEnd() can receive 'struct node *'
  // address i.e. insertEnd(struct node **l, .....)

  if (*l==NULL) *l=temp;
  struct node* p=*l;
  while (p->next!=NULL) p=p->next;
  p->next=temp;
```

When first node will be inserted, list head will point to `temp`, then `p` will be initialised with list head and `while` loop condition (`pp->next!=NULL`) will be `false` and `p->next` will be assigned to `temp` i.e. to itself.

So, when the `insertEnd()` called to insert second node to list the `while` loop loops forever in circular list. The insertion at the end of list should be in `else` part of `if (l==NULL)` which is missing in your code. It should be like this

```
  if (*l==NULL) {
    *l=temp;
  } else {
    struct node* p=*l;
    while (p->next!=NULL) p=p->next;
    p->next=temp;
  }
```

Comment: makes sense thank you so much :)