# syntax error of linked lists in dynamic memory in C language

Tags: c, dynamic, malloc

```
void push(struct node* head,int data)
{
    struct node* newnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
    newnode->data=data;
    newnode->next=head;
    head=newnode; //it doesnt work
}
```

This code is not working; the error that occured was not a syntax error.

Comment: So is it a syntax error or not a syntax error?
You need to declare the parameter as `struct node** head` and change the last statement to `*head=newnode`.

Comment: the change to `head` won't be visible outside the `push` function, and I presume that's exactly what you'd like.

Comment: code is not working means a lot, please point out your error.

Comment: the code is taken from a book..where the writer assumes that this code doesnt work

Comment: @isedev why it wont be visible ?

Comment: @77981 All function parameters are passed by value in C. So the `head` variable within the `push` function is not the same `head` variable that the caller passed in (it's just the same value). So changing one does not affect the other. The variable needs to be passed in as `struct node **head;` and set with `*head=newnode;`.

Comment: A syntax error means it doesn't compile, and as a result you can't even attempt to run it.  It sounds instead like this is a functional error.  The last statement, where you assign to `head`, is dead code since it has no effect after the function returns.  `head` is just a function argument, which is basically a type of local variable that is bound upon entry to the function.  You probably intended to pass a *pointer* to head so that you can change it in the caller.

Comment: see [C: change pointer passed by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531765/c-change-pointer-passed-by-value)

Comment: if the function is not void,and it returns the variable head,does it work ?

Comment: Yes that is another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters in C are *passed by value*, rather than *passed by reference*, that is, formal parameters are just **copies** of actual parameters. Maybe you can understand why the following function doesn't work:

```
void negate(int num)
{
    num = -num; // Doesn't work
}
```

The reason why the posted code doesn't work is just similar. `head = newnode;` only changes the value of formal parameter `head`. After `push()` returns, the value of actual parameters from the caller remain unmodified. Thus, for the caller, nothing happens(expect that a block of memory is `malloc()`ed but not `free()`ed).

To change the value of variables, you must pass their address to functions:

```
void push(struct node **head,int data)
{
    struct node* newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
    newnode->data = data;
    newnode->next = head;
    *head = newnode;
}
```

See also: [How do I modify a pointer that has been passed into a function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/766893/5399734)